# The procedure entry point ... could not be located in the dynamic link library (Path to file)

Tags: c++, dll, file-read

I'm having trouble reading from a text file in C++, so basically I want to read the text file on "cmd" using this code, however, an error pops up.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "helloworld.h"

using namespace::std;
int main(){
    string line;
    ifstream file("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/Progra/Seminario.txt");
    if(file.is_open()){
            cout << line << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    else{
        cout << "File is not open" << endl;
    }

}
```

When I compile it, I get no errors, however, when I run a.exe, a window pops up saying:

> The procedure entry point _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1Ev could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Progra\a.exe.

How can I fix this? Or is there any other way to read from a file?

Comment: What compiler environment? It's possible that your program doesn't correctly dynamically link to a required runtime library.

Comment: @cdhowie I am using the Mingw compiler, so I compiled it as follows: g++ helloworld.cpp

Comment: @Aumnayan Am I unable to bump posts?

Comment: @Lithorz You created a new thread. Identical to the first but without the comments made by previous reviewers. I understand that it's still an open issue with you, but having identical threads undermines the process to a solution.

Comment: @Aumnayan my bad, Im sorry. Ill keep posting on the other thread then